# Running Mahout on Hadoop Cluster

Tags: hadoop, mahout

I am a Mahout/Hadoop Beginner.

I am trying to run Mahout examples given in "Mahout in Action" Book. I am able to run the examples in Eclipse without Hadoop. 
Can you please let me know how to run the same examples in the Hadoop Cluster.

Answer (score 2):

This [wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Algorithms) page has the different articles implemented in Mahout and how to run them. Many of them take the below as an argument

> -xm "execution method: sequential or mapreduce"

Mahout [requirements](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/System+Requirements) mention that it works on Hadoop 0.20.0+. See this tutorial on how to setup Hadoop on a [single node](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) and on a [multi node cluster](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/) on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks Praveen Sripathi. I have a Hadoop Cluster setup. Right now I am able to run it through Eclipse. Can you please let me know the command line syntax for running a sample code of Mahout in Hadoop Cluster. Say I have a RecommenderIntro.java file which is packaged in mia.recommender.ch02 package. Should I create a jar out of this and run it as I run Hadoop sample examples? Can you brief me on that.

Comment: I didn't go into the specific details, but your approach is correct. Check the Mahout documentation, if it doesn't help post another query in SO. Also, see how one of the examples is implemented and you will know the details.